# Vagrant - centos networking

Tags: nginx, centos, vagrant, centos7

I have set up a Vagrant machine with this configuration --

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "intprog/centos7-ez6"
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.243"
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "/server/bin/nginx/conf/domains-enabled/cemcloudMigration.conf", destination: "~/cemcloud.conf"
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "webroot/bootstrap/script.sh"
end
```

This is how my script looks like -- sudo su

```
#update the centos version
#yum update -y

yum -y erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util
#getting nginx from the right address
yum install -y http://http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.10.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y nginx

#installing composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
chmod +x composer.phar
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

cd /srv/www/cemcloud2
composer install

#removal of old mariadb5.5 and installation of the new one
yum -y remove mariadb-server mariadb mariadb-libs
yum clean all
yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client

#clear unnecessary software
yum -y remove varnish

## restart the service
service mysql restart
service php-fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

/var/log/nginx/access.log is producing this --

> 10.0.2.2 - - [17/Oct/2016:11:42:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/51.0" "-"

Really strange behavior from nginx because it some times produces log and sometimes it doesn't. When I open up my firefox developer it produces log and when I am on google chrome it doesn't.

Every time I put in the URL into browser it says

> the connection has timed out.

Anyhow I want to get connected to this machine. What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your network on the guest-mashine with:

```
nmap -sT -O localhost
```

Check if the ports your are using in your nginx configuration are open.
If not, open them in your firewall and check again.

Answer (score 1):

It was a firewall issue inside this machine "intprog/centos7-ez6". It wasn't listening to the port https. 
I have followed those steps:

1. `firewall-cmd --add-service=https`
2. `firewall-cmd --add-service=https --permanent`
3. `firewall-cmd --reload`

and it all worked.